# Vue warning Error in data() "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, undefined, warnings, typeerror

does anybody know how I can get rid of this warning? I guess it happens because I try to do something with an undefined object? Any help would be very much appreciated! Thank you! Here is my code:

```html
        <v-card class="ma-3 pa-3" v-for="item in state.monitorAll[0]" v-bind:key="item.countdown">
          <v-row>
            <div class="ma-3">Minuten bis zum nächsten Halt:  <v-avatar class="ml-2 blue white--text">{{ item.departureTime.countdown }}</v-avatar></div>
            <v-avatar v-if="typeof item.vehicle == 'undefined'" class="ma-3 ml-5 green"><v-icon class="white--text">accessible</v-icon></v-avatar>
          </v-row>
        </v-card>

<script>
  import axios from 'axios'
  import {onMounted, reactive} from '@vue/composition-api'

  export default {
    name: 'App',
    setup() {
      let state = reactive({
        wlData: '',
        monitorAll: [],
      })
       async function showData() {
        let config = {
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:8080',
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
          }
        }
        const wlData = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/ogd_realtime/monitor?rbl=832', config);
        state.wlData = wlData.data.data['monitors'];
        state.monitorAll = state.wlData.map(monitor => monitor.lines[0].departures.departure);
      }

      let startLoad = onMounted(() => {
        console.log('component is mounted!');
        showData();
      })

      return {
        state,
        showData,
        startLoad,
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Guessing it's this line `state.wlData = wlData.data.data['monitors'];`  Do you need 2x `data`?  Also, the console should tell you what line registered the error.

Comment: what line does the error appear on

Comment: it just tells me in the App component

Comment: in this line pretty much: webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:620

Comment: The problem cannot be solved because it lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and doesn't contain any valuable clues. Only you can debug it. There's no full error (even if line numbers don't tell anything, navigating to respective lines can give some idea). Consider providing a way to replicate the problem. If this is possible with static JSON file that contains a response from your server then it's ok. As it was said, `state.wlData =` looks suspicious, also it's unclear why you expect it to be an array (`.map`) while it's a string (`''`), although none of this should cause this error.

Comment: Also `v-for="item in state.monitorAll[0]"` is clearly another problem because initially `monitorAll[0] === undefined`, but it shouldn't cause exactly this error too.

Comment: Ya, I am quite new to all of this. Thanks for the help! I just found out that the problem is in the "let startLoad = onMounted", if I get rid of this function the warning is gone..

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was the onMounted that caused the problem.
I guess it is because the onMounted is called before there is any value in the showData(). I am not sure. I deleted;

> let startLoad = onMounted(() => {
>   console.log('component is mounted!');
>   showData();
>   })

and just called showData() directly after the async function showData() is being created.
I have no idea why this works and I guess it is not the best way to handle it, but at least I lost my warning!